# Accessibility error with headings out of order in mega menu. They appear above the h1 but need to use h2 to provide context to the ul

Tags: user-interface, accessibility, wcag2.0

How should you handle h tags in the main menu of your site if the main menu renders above the h1?

Is it ok to break heading hierarchy in this case to provide the additional semantics / hierarchy, or should a different element be used instead of heading tags?

For example:

- You have menu that shows a secondary menu on hover / focus / click.
- It uses a checkbox input to indicate the state of the menu so as to allow the menu to stay open.
- The secondary menus use h2 > ul >li > a to organize and provide additional hierarchy to the overall menu.
- Third level link lists follow the heading hierarchy, eg., h3 > ul > li > a

CodePen link for more clarity :: https://codepen.io/uxmfdesign/pen/yLBrMmd

```
<header>
  <div class="main-menu__container">
    <input 
      class="main-menu__toggle webaim-hidden" 
      type="checkbox" 
      id="main-menu-toggle-block-main-menu"> 

    <!-- toggle open close -->
    <label 
      class="main-menu__label" 
      for="main-menu-toggle-block-main-menu" 
      aria-label="Toggle Main menu"
      > 
        Main menu
    </label>
    <nav class="main-menu__nav">
      <div 
        class="main-menu-group" 
        data-main-menu-group=""> 
          <!-- toggle open close of menu section -->
          <input 
            id="main-menu-group-toggle-block-main-menu-0" 
            type="checkbox" 
            name="main-menu-group" 
            class="main-menu-group__toggle webaim-hidden" 
            data-main-menu-group-toggle=""> 

          <label 
            for="main-menu-group-toggle-block-main-menu-0" 
            aria-label="Open Our services" 
            aria-haspopup="true" 
            data-icon="" 
            class="main-menu-group__toggle-label"> 
            Section title
          </label>
        <div class="main-menu-group__wrapper">
          <h2 class="main-menu-group__heading">
            <span>Section title</span>
          </h2>
          <ul class="main-menu-nav-list">
            <li class="main-menu-nav-list__item">
              <h3 class="main-menu-nav-list__title">
                <a class="main-menu-nav-list__title-link" href="/ca-domains">
                  Sub-section title
                </a>
              </h3>
              <ul class="main-menu-subnav-list__menu">
                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item main-menu-subnav-list__item--with-sub">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/register-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/optimize-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="main-menu-nav-list__item">
              <h3 class="main-menu-nav-list__title">
                <a class="main-menu-nav-list__title-link" href="/ca-domains">
                  Sub-section title
                </a>
              </h3>
              <ul class="main-menu-subnav-list__menu">
                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item main-menu-subnav-list__item--with-sub">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/register-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/optimize-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div 
        class="main-menu-group" 
        data-main-menu-group=""> 
          <!-- toggle open close of menu section -->
          <input 
            id="main-menu-group-toggle-block-main-menu-0" 
            type="checkbox" 
            name="main-menu-group" 
            class="main-menu-group__toggle webaim-hidden" 
            data-main-menu-group-toggle=""> 

          <label 
            for="main-menu-group-toggle-block-main-menu-0" 
            aria-label="Open Our services" 
            aria-haspopup="true" 
            data-icon="" 
            class="main-menu-group__toggle-label"> 
            Section title
          </label>
        <div class="main-menu-group__wrapper">
          <h2 class="main-menu-group__heading">
            <span>Section title</span>
          </h2>
          <ul class="main-menu-nav-list">
            <li class="main-menu-nav-list__item">
              <h3 class="main-menu-nav-list__title">
                <a class="main-menu-nav-list__title-link" href="/ca-domains">
                  Sub-section title
                </a>
              </h3>
              <ul class="main-menu-subnav-list__menu">
                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item main-menu-subnav-list__item--with-sub">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/register-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/optimize-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="main-menu-nav-list__item">
              <h3 class="main-menu-nav-list__title">
                <a class="main-menu-nav-list__title-link" href="/ca-domains">
                  Sub-section title
                </a>
              </h3>
              <ul class="main-menu-subnav-list__menu">
                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item main-menu-subnav-list__item--with-sub">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/register-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="main-menu-subnav-list__item">
                  <a class="main-menu-subnav-list__link" href="/ca-domains/optimize-your-ca">
                    sub-page name
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>
    The problem heading is here
  </h1>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I should have double checked that my markdown copies properly.

Comment: Sorry, a moderator has removed my answer *(an edit would have been more efficient)*. Yes, you can. It's described by the WAI in [Example 2: Main heading after navigation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/#main-heading-after-navigation).

Comment: Thanks @Adam. exact answer I was looking for.